# What does the assembly keyword mean in the AssemblyInfo.cs. Does it permit to use method inside?

Tags: c#, .net

Saw some code snippet inside AssemblyInfo.cs like

```
[assembly: someattributename]
```

What does this code mean?

I even saw some method to be used inside assembly, like

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

Is this the attribute anymore?

Answer (score 19):

Attributes are always applied to an element (e.g. a method, property). The "assembly:" prefix means that the attribute (the part you omitted using '***') is [applied to the assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfz783fz.aspx).

> **Applying Attributes at the Assembly Level** If you want to apply an attribute at the assembly level, use the Assembly keyword. The following code shows the AssemblyNameAttribute applied at the assembly level.
>
> ```
> using System.Reflection;
> [assembly:AssemblyTitle("My Assembly")]
> ```
>
> When this attribute is applied, the string "MyAssembly" is placed in the assembly manifest in the metadata portion of the file. You can view the attribute either by using the MSIL Disassembler (Ildasm.exe) or by creating a custom program to retrieve the attribute.

Answer (score 9):

`assembly:` is what's known as an *attribute target*. It specifies that the attribute applies to the assembly itself, and not to any of the types within the assembly. Some other attribute targets are `module`, `return` and `param`.

See "[Attributes (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z0w1kczw.aspx)".

Comment: I think this is the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 8):

It means this an [attribute on the assembly itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s.aspx) and not on a specific class, method, property etc.

Answer (score 3):

Those are assembly attributes, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s.aspx).

They make up the version information for your assembly (or: executable) for example.

Answer (score 2):

General Information about this assembly is controlled through this set of attributes.

a simple explanation is shown in this [Link](http://dontangg.github.com/nocco/properties/assemblyinfo.html)

Answer (score 1):

To the second (edited) part of your answer:

No, it is not a method call. `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator` is also an [attribute](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfiguratorAttribute.html) defined by log4net. (See the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) for log4net details.) Its exact declaration is

```
public class XmlConfiguratorAttribute : ConfiguratorAttribute
```

What is a little bit misleading in this case is the attribute naming convention. That means when you use an attribute (even on assembly level) you can leave the `Attribute` suffix from the attribute class name.